# Python Directory Syntax

Tags: python, directory, canopy

I'm opening a file in the Canopy Editor. The instructions I have say that I should use the command:

```
!type ch06/ex1.csv
```

My trouble is that I can't seem to open `ex1.csv` unless I am in the `ch06` folder and using

```
!type ex1.csv
```

That folder is located within a folder comprising all of the chapter resource folders. How do I open the file when the directory is set to the overall folder?

- I've replaced the original `!cat` with `!type`, which has to do with the editor I'm using or the version of Python or something.

How do I open a .csv file that is in a sub folder of the current directory?

Comment: I can't see what this has to do with Python. This is not Python syntax at all.

Comment: I took `!cat ch06/ex1.csv` directly from "Python for Data Analysis."

Comment: It's just an editor command, unrelated to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The lead "!" in the above command is ipython "magic" for invoking an OS shell command  Shell commands are OS-specific (they are "DOS" commands in Windows, bash commands in Mac or Linux). The Windows `type` command is equivalent to the Linux/Mac `cat` command.

2) To change ipython's cwd (current working directory) in canopy, use the working directory drop-down menu in the upper right of Canopy's python pane. This will construct an ipython "magic" `%cd` command for you. Or, once you are familiar with this concept, just use a `%cd` directly. For more information, see [Change Directory in the Canopy User Guide](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html#change-directory).